# How to get self process id in Flex Desktop App

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I create a Flex Desktop App by Flex builder 4

I want to log some debug info into a file , named by process id

```
//var pid:int = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.getPid() ??
var logFile:String = "/var/log/MyApp_"+pid+".log";
```

Is these any API to get pid in Flex/ActionScript3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get processes from a C# console application and pick out the process that your flex application is using. I made an example of this:

GetProcesses.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GetProcesses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

            String processesXml = "";

            processesXml += "<processes>\n";

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                processesXml += "\t<process id='" + process.Id + "' name='" + process.ProcessName + "' />\n";

            }// end foreach

            processesXml += "</processes>";

            Console.WriteLine(processesXml);

        }// end method

    }// end class

}// end namespace
```

Main.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _nativeProcess:NativeProcess;
        private var _nativeProcessSUI:NativeProcessStartupInfo;
        private var _processes:XML;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            _nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
            _nativeProcessSUI = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

            _nativeProcessSUI.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("GetProcesses.exe");
            _nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onNativeProcessSOD);
            _nativeProcess.addEventListener(Event.STANDARD_OUTPUT_CLOSE, onNativeProcessSOC);
            _nativeProcess.start(_nativeProcessSUI);

        }// end function

        private function onNativeProcessSOD(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            _processes = XML(_nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(_nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));

        }// end function

        private function onNativeProcessSOC(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(_processes.process.(@name == "GetProcesses").@id); // 7192

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

The C# console application "GetProcesses.cs" creates an xml of processes using the `GetProcesses()` method and the flex application retrieves that xml. In this example I use

```
trace(_processes.process.(@name == "GetProcesses").@id); // 7192
```

to get the process ID of the C# console application but obviously you would change the process name in the xml query to the process name your flex application is using.

Comment: Thank you . I write a python app for that.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that you can find the pid of your currently running application. The only place where you can get some info about your app is [NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html).

If you really need the pid you can create a second application that acts like a launcher. This new application starts and create a new process for the real application that you've already created using [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html). In this way you have all the information about the process.

Remember that if you use NativeProcess launching you have some limitation (for example you can't use web install)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is included because each OS has a different way to get process id.  You could try to do a NativeProcess call to [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28VS.85%29.aspx)  but I'm not sure if it'll work.

Comment: It would only work for Air applications (since NativeProcess can't be done in Flex only)

Comment: I mean, it won't work because newly started process will have its own PID, not AIR app's PID. And for Flex app PID may not have sense at all - they may execute in the browser process, not their own.